# Regular expression using grep to extract an IP address

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to parse the default IP address of the default route.

I already have the default route and I'm trying to extract the IP address from it.

```
/sbin/ip addr show dev eth0 | grep 'inet'
```

Gets me as far as the correct line where the IP address is:

```
inet 10.1.4.33/22 brd 10.1.83.255 scope global eth0
```

And I need help extracting the IP address part 10.1.4.33

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pipe your output to `grep -o`:

`/sbin/ip addr show dev eth0 | grep 'inet' | grep -oE "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | head -n 1`

The `head -n 1` is required to select the first match only.

Comment: It involves two `grep` and one `head` call, all this can be done in a single `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk`:

```
/sbin/ip addr show dev eth0 | awk -F '[ /\t]+' '$2=="inet"{print $3; exit}'
192.168.0.52
```

Answer (score 1):

try one more approach in awk too.

```
/sbin/ip addr show dev eth0 | awk '{match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/);if(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) && $0 ~ /inet/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

For completion of the options available, using sed:

```
ip add show dev eth0 | sed -rn 's@^.*inet[[:blank:]]([[:digit:]]{1,3}(.[[:digit:]]{1,3}){3})/.*$@\1@p'
```

Answer (score 0):

No complicated regular expression is needed.

```
output=$(/sbin/ip addr show dev eth0 | grep 'inet')
[[ $output = inet\ (.*)/ ]] && ip_addr=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```